# "Missing credentials in config" with aws-amplify Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I recently upgraded from an older version of aws-amplify to version

`"aws-amplify": "^1.0.2"`

and when doing so I immediately started getting errors when trying to upload to my bucket. 
`[WARN] 38:42.445 StorageClass - error uploading": CredentialsError: "Missing credentials in config"`

After some digging I discovered that  some new keys were added to the Storage configuration in the most recent version of aws-amplify; "credentials" and "level". The documentation does not mentioned these in any way, and I am unable to find exactly what value this "credentials" key needs in order to work properly (with a manual configuration of Auth and Storage). Anyone have any ideas of what this credentials object should look like?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm in the same case ...

Comment: Just give up of Amplify and Cognito. Use Firebase you will have no more problems.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set the credentials key manually, the Amplify is setting the credentials for the Storage class automatically. Since your environment was working prior the update the issue maybe related with `aws-sdk` packages. The issue is related with multiple `aws-sdk` packages in your `node_modules` folder. As a rule simple removing an `aws-sdk` folder is not working since your project files are cached. Below are steps how to fix the issue for a `react-native` project but you can adjust them according to your environment:

1. Make sure you do not have `aws-sdk` under dependencies in your `package.json` file since `aws-amplify` already has AWS SDK included. If there is an `aws-sdk` in the `package.json` file run the command to remove it:

   ```
   $ npm uninstall aws-sdk --save
   ```
2. Make sure you are using the latest version of `aws-amplify` package.
3. Remove the `package-lock.json` file from your project folder (do not forget to create a copy of the file).
4. Run

   ```
   $ rm -rf node_modules && npm install
   ```

   This command will remove your `node_modules` folder and reinstall all the packages according to the `package.json` file.
5. Optionally you can clear your local caches by entering one-by-one the following commands:

   ```
   $ watchman watch-del-all
   $ rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*
   $ rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Amplify is using aws-sdk to fetch `credentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey)`. But it's not found because you may haven't configured it. So configure it before you configure aws-amplify. No need to uninstall anything.

```
AWS.config.update({...credential})
Amplify.configure({...credential})
```

Comment: But where is this done???
is this in script in terminal.
this issue is all over the place but knowone providing an answer gives a location to action these things.